# Différence entre "se faire mourir" et "mourir"

Tags: sens, conditionnel

> Mariane : **Je me ferais mourir**, épouser Tartuffe cela est mon dernier
> désir et je préfère encore me faire mourir !

Je ne comprends pas l'usage de *se faire mourir* ici. Pourquoi l'auteur n'a pas écrit *je mourrais* ou *je me tuerais* ? Quelle est la différence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Se faire mourir*, c'est un moyen démodé de dire *se tuer* / *se suicider*. Toutes les trois veulent dire la même chose.